# Redux best practice for sharing data between states

Tags: redux

I'm working on an webapp using redux, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to sharing data between two substates.

Lets say I have a data structure like so, for an app where a user can order food from an italian restaurant:

```
{
    "entrees": [{ "type": "pizza", "sauce": "alfredo", "topping": "meat" }],
    "options": {
        "entreeTypes": ["pizza", "calzone"],
        "sauceTypes": {
            "pizza": ["marinara", "white"],
            "calzone": ["marinara", "alfredo"]
        },
        "toppingTypes": {
            "marinara": ["meat", "veggies", "cheese"],
            "white": ["meat", "veggies"],
            "alfredo": ["meat"] 
        }
    }
}
```

So if the user wants to add an entree to their order, the new entree should populate all the default options for type, sauce, and topping, which here would be "pizza", "marinara", and "meat".

Ideally, I'd like this addition of an entree to take place in the *entrees* reducer. However, the *entrees* reducer would need access to various parts of the *options* state to accomplish its goal.

My present implementation looks something like this (using *redux-thunk*):

```
function addEntree(){

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const options = getState().options;
        const type = options.entreeTypes[0];
        const sauce = options.sauceTypes[type][0];
        const topping = options.toppingTypes[sauce][0];
        const action = { type: 'ADD_ENTREE', type, sauce, topping };
        dispatch(action);

    };
}
```

Where the action gets picked up by the entrees reducer.

So my question is, does this seem in good practice? Is anyone else using patterns they find to be superior?

Answer (score 0):

The example is a but odd because typically options aren't part of the application state. Moreover, it seems like you want a hierarchy of choices, where you can't have veggies with your alfredo. So two things:

1. If the options can be constants outside of application state because they are dynamic, do that. So basically store your current `options` reducer as a `const` somewhere and you can just import it.
2. If the ingredient list and combinations are dynamic, I don't think you should be enforcing the ingredient combination restrictions in your actions. If you have a order page, for example, load all of the options in the props. Voilá, you have access to multiple reducers at once. In the situation where the user has selected "Pizza" but not the sauce or topping, you would select the first sauce in `props.options.sauceTypes[selectedEntree]`, and then `props.options.toppingTypes[selectedSauce]`

   ```
   class OrderPage extends React.Component {
     ...
     function onSelectEntree (entree) {
       const { options: { sauceTypes, toppingTypes }, addEntree } = this.props;
       const sauce = sauceTypes[entree][0];
       const topping = toppingTypes[sauce][0];

       addEntree(entree, sauce, topping):
       // Or if you don't want to persist it globally yet:
       // this.setState({ entree, sauce, topping });
     }
     ...
   }
   ```

   Then in the view, show only the options that are allowed given the current selection that the user has made (ie, hide veggies if they picked alfredo). Do validation in the component.